# Put latitude and longitude on a UILabel programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, core-location

I can't seem to get the latitude and longitude to show up on the labels. I've tried many things though I'm guessing it might be something simple.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit  

class LocationVC: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    var location: CLLocation! {
        didSet{
            longLabel.text = ("\(location.coordinate.latitude)")

            latLabel.text  = ("\(location.coordinate.longitude)")
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let location = locations[0]

        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.5, 0.5)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)

        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        print("hhhhh\(location.coordinate.latitude)")

        print(location.altitude)
        print(location.speed)

        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }
```

All the views are set up correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You did not change the value of the `location` variable of your class, which would trigger the text change of the label. Append this to `didUpdateLocations`:

```
self.location = location
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
longLabel.text = location.coordinate.latitude.description
latLabel.text  = location.coordinate.longitude.description
```

Comment: Don't use description. use number formatter or String(format:) initializer

Comment: i tried self.location  = location with didUpdateLocations and the put in latLabel.text = location.coordinate.latitude.description  ,but it still does not change anything?